# extracting month and year from object of POSIX Dates and Times Classes in r

Tags: r, posixlt

I tried to extract month and year from an object of POSIXlt class, however, the returned month seemed to be one month earlier and the year did not seem correct either. My R code is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The POSIXlt stores month of the year using 0 to 11 (0 for Jan, 11 for Dec), and the year is counted as years since 1990.